# "ld: framework not found GGLAnalytics for architecture x86_64" error on Test target

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, cocoapods

I recently added CocoaPods to my app in order to use Google Analytics. The app runs fine, but unit tests no longer build. I get the following error when trying to run unit tests:

```
ld: framework not found GGLAnalytics for architecture x86_64
```

Here is my Podfile:

```
target 'MyApp' do

  use_frameworks!

  pod 'Google/Analytics'

  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

I tried putting `pod 'Google/Analytics'` within the test targets, then ran `pod install` and `pod update`, cleaned the build, deleted derived data, nothing helped. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Seems to be same thing as discussed here: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/5514. Does anyone know how to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

This problem was resolved by upgrading to CocoaPods 1.2.1.beta.1 (`sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`) and re-running `pod install`.